# How to style a <p> inside a div with css

Tags: css, html

I found this way works but will it cause any class conflicts if I restyle a `<p>` element inline?

```
p, .main-column {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: robotolight, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6zt6mcg/2/)

I am trying to compact my HTML by not styling inline `<p>` elements

Comment: i am trying to compact my HTML by not styling inline p elements

Comment: You should add the comment along with your Question I guess.

Comment: @user3168736 no i am stlying the p element look at the js fiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding css for a specific div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255356/overriding-css-for-a-specific-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set those styles just for `p` elements inside the `main-column` div, target them like this:

```
.main-column p {}
```

Also, make sure to use an actual heading element for you headings, such as `h1`, `h2` etc., rather than a styled span.

Comment: i do have h1 h2 on my pages, i did not add it to the fiddle

Comment: `.main-column p {}` works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/w6zt6mcg/4/)**

If you want particular style for `<p>` just place it inside particular div like `.main-column p` so that style works only if its inside `.main-column div`

CSS:

```
.main-column p, .main-column {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: robotolight, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: that works to, what should i use?  `.main-column p, .main-column {` or `p,.main-column`

Answer (score 0):

```
p .main-column {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: robotolight, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```